# How to free memory allocated by ImageIcon? I have a infinite loop with "new ImageIcon" and i need free each image after display.

Tags: java, swing, memory, memory-management, imageicon

How to free memory allocated by ImageIcon? I have an infinite loop with "new ImageIcon ..." and i need to free the memory allocated by each image after displaying it on the screen. The display interval between images is 200 ms. Does anyone have a simple and efficient solution to avoid the growing consumption of memory? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you share your code snippet?

Comment: I call this function infinite times: public void setImagem(String Imagem) {
        if (Imagem != null) {
            imagem = new ImageIcon(Imagem).getImage();
        } else {
            imagem = null;
        }

        repaint();
    }

Comment: *"Does anyone have a simple and efficient solution to avoid the growing consumption of memory?"*  Ignore it.  The JVM will GC when it needs to.

Answer (score 2):

If you not reusing the images and want to discard the system cached data, take a look at [`ImageIcon#getImage#flush`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#flush%28%29)

> Flushes all reconstructable resources being used by this Image object.
>   This includes any pixel data that is being cached for rendering to the
>   screen as well as any system resources that are being used to store
>   data or pixels for the image if they can be recreated. The image is
>   reset to a state similar to when it was first created so that if it is
>   again rendered, the image data will have to be recreated or fetched
>   again from its source.

Comment: I tried your suggestion without success. The memory continues increasing each "new ImageIcon". I think (i am ignorant, no offense) that "flush" only process pending actions but not free memory allocated by "ImageIcon" (maybe i´m wrong). Have you another "magic card" to show? Thank you very much!

Comment: `flush` would basically allow the resources previously allocated by the `ImageIcon`, which they may become available for garbage allocation at some time in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much MadProgrammer! I will flush every time i use "new ImageIcon". Have a very nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Simply after the fnal painting of the image, say `images.get(i)` remove the held image: `images.set(i, null)`. In this way the garbage collector can remove it.

Comment: I will try each answer. Thanks a lot guys, i really appreciate your quick support.

Comment: I tried using it and could not reach success because I'm ignorant. When I type "Images.get (i); Images.set (i, null)" the interpreter NetBeans expects something more, type "set what, or get what?" and, as I said I am ignorant and do not know what to say to the interpreter associate my code with the proper function. Can you help me? The code is:
     public void set picture (Picture String) {
         if (Image! = null) {
             image = new ImageIcon (Picture). getImage ();
         Else {}
             image = null;
         }
         repaint ();
     }

Comment: Sorry, I was the ignorant here; after writing it, you expanded your question. I assumed you held the created images in a class field, and in the paint(Component) method drew the next image. With image the only memory leak is either a reference held, or `createGraphics` without `dispose`. Sorry, maybe you do a `add(new JLabel(imageicon))` too ininetely? That would cause a problem.

Comment: I'm trying to create a desktop application (java swing) and I find it very annoying form using the "look and feel", static image, degrade or something. So I created some animations, something like an animated gif, but in my case is a sequence of 20 images 1024x640 jpg (each form) and I'm creating forms like animated wallpapers. This is the problem - how to release the image above to allocate a new image sequence without using more and more memory?